# How to show transparent sliding menu on activity

Tags: android

I am using Jfeinstein10 sliding menu lib and i want to show transparent sliding menu on my activity .I have searched but didn't get anything . 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by transparent sliding menu? Which part of sliding menu you want transparent?

Comment: I want  the menu (transparent) which toggles and which comes on main activity ,not pushing the activity towards left/right.

Comment: Then  Jfeinstein10 sliding menu is no use of yours. You need to find any other library? Checkout the sample app of Jfeinstein10 sliding menu [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example&hl=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit the `Jfeinstein10 sliding menu lib` . you can change the `background` property to set `Transperent`.